# Имеет ли значение порядок элементов в множестве?

Tags: математика, множества, дискретная-математика

Предположим, есть множество A из 10 разных чисел. Множество B содержит те же числа, но в другом порядке. Множество A равно множеству B?

Прошу прощения, если вопрос некорректный с точки зрения математики. Поправьте, пожалуйста, если что.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С точки зрения математики это тождественные множества.

Comment: Но сам порядок элементов в множестве имеет значение? Им можно присвоить порядковый номер? Это останется множеством, или будет чем-то другим?

Comment: Нет. Множество - это просто неупорядоченный (в смысле, что порядок значения не имеет) набор элементов. Упорядоченное множество - это уже **кортеж**.

Comment: Кортеж... А в математике есть какое-нибудь обозначение?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE

Comment: Точно, спасибо.

Comment: А если кортеж A содержит n одинаковых чисел, а кортеж B является перестановкой чисел кортежа A, A = B?

Comment: @Андрей Нет, потому что в кортеже порядок имеет значение

Comment: @Mikhailo, теперь понятно, спасибо.